# Hover on badge doesn't show the title of the badge

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges

In the Badge section, when I hover over a tag badge, the text/title disappears.

Without hover:

[image: No Hover]

After hover:

[image: On Hover]

The same thing is happening on the dupe-hammered questions too.

[image: Dupe-Hammered]

This is happening on Chrome 48, Firefox 43 and Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: Also on Safari 9.0.3.  Can you include which browser version you're using?

Comment: Yeah, not sure what the point of making the background color and text color the same on hover... Oversight seems likely.

Comment: The solution is to change the color of the text on hover, `.badge-tag:hover { color: #ccc; }`.

Comment: This appears very lately (a few days ago, at most).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue. It has been corrected, as you can see in the photo attached.

[image]

Comment: Yes, just checked that and it's solved! Thanks SE team!